# Balanced Tensor Product of Module Categories

Tags: category-theory, tensor-products, monoidal-categories

Let $C$ be a $k$-linear ($Vect_k$-enriched) monoidal category and consider the 2-category $Mod_{C}$ of $k$-linear $(C,C)$-bimodule categories in the sense of Ostrik (https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0111139.). Roughly speaking, this construction can be thought of as a ``categorification" of a module over a ring. Let $\otimes_C$ denote the tensor product of $k$-linear $(C,C)$-bimodule categories(as defined in the work of Douglas, Schommer-Pries, and N. Snyder in https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.4204.)

Does $\otimes_C$ endow $Mod_{C}$ with the structure of a monoidal 2-category?

Comment: You mean a monoidal 2-category, and probably.

Comment: ah yes, thats what I meant.

Comment: You would probably fare better on mathoverflow, IMO. The second paper you're quoting is barely 2 years old, if this doesn't qualify as research I don't know what does.